# Repairing file for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm trying to get the this [image] file 3D printed, but got the following feedback from a service:

> 1.The wall thickness of the whole part is too thin which has a high risk of crack, loss and deformation. Could you please kindly increase
> it to be at least 2.0mm to proceed?
>
> 2.The part is hollow in the middle, there is risk of collapse. Please add support rails for the part, and the thickness of the support rails
> should be at least.
>
> 3.There should be some escape holes add to the hollow part,otherwise the excess materials will stuck inside the part
>
> 4.There are some bad edges and errors need to be fixed in your file. Could you please kindly modify and repair the file so that we can
> proceed?

I've tried to look into Blender's *3D Print* and choosing *Make Manifold*, but that seems to sort of remove the entire model.

Any feedback, ideas, comments on how to the most easy fix the file for 3D printing is very much appreciated, without needing to manual model the object.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: A good video that explains the 3D print toolbox and how to fix the issues it finds can be found here https://youtu.be/0rgrLWFUjlk